# Using .map() function

Tags: javascript, function, protractor

I have this JS:

```
var getAccountNumberArray =  element.all(by.repeater('currentUserAccount in currentUserAccounts').column('currentUserAccount.accountNumber')).map(function (accounts) {
                return accounts.getText();
            });

            getAccountNumberArray.then(function (textArr) {
            console.log(textArr);
        });
    });
```

which works great, however I would like to place it in a function to call when I like,

```
MyAccountsPage.prototype.getAccountNumberArray = function () {
    element.all(by.repeater('currentUserAccount in currentUserAccounts').column('currentUserAccount.accountNumber')).map(function (accounts){
        return accounts.getText();
        });
};
```

Why does this function return `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return result from function

```
MyAccountsPage.prototype.getAccountNumberArray = function() {
    return element.all(by.repeater('currentUserAccount in currentUserAccounts').column('currentUserAccount.accountNumber')).map(function(accounts) {
        return accounts.getText();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyAccountsPage.prototype.getAccountNumberArray = function () {
    return element.all(by.repeater('currentUserAccount in currentUserAccounts').column('currentUserAccount.accountNumber')).map(function (accounts){
        return accounts.getText();
        });
};
```

You need to return it -- functions without an explicit `return` statement return `undefined`.